# How can I get the script name of the script that launched my program in batch and powershell?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

So I have a situation where I'll run a script, let's call it `test.bat`, and this script will at some point run my C# program, `myprogram.exe`. I need a way to obtain the name of the script that called `myprogram.exe`, so that when I see the output of that function, it is `test.bat`.

Right now I am using this code:

```
string GetParentProcessName()
{
    int myId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
    string query = string.Format("SELECT ParentProcessId FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = {0}", myId);
    ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", query);
    var results = search.Get().GetEnumerator();
    results.MoveNext();
    var queryObj = results.Current;
    var parentId = (uint)queryObj["ParentProcessId"];
    Process parent = Process.GetProcessById((int)parentId);
    Console.WriteLine("My parent process name is: {0}", parent.ProcessName);
    return parent.ProcessName;
}
```

However the output when I run `test.bat` in the command line is "cmd", not "test" or "test.bat".

How can I do this?

Comment: I think the trouble here is that `test.bat` isn't really an executable; it's a script that's interpreted by `cmd.exe`.  Not that this helps you achieve your purpose...

Comment: Presumably you are not in control of the script that launches you? On the off chance you are, the obvious fix is to pass a paramater to your EXE, telling it the name of the script.

Comment: You query the `commandline` property of the cmd.exe process to find your script's name.

Comment: @bgalea, I tried querying that with WMI but what I actually got was the call to my program that the script made. So for example if my test.bat called my script with `myprogram.exe -a "Some Text"` that's what I'm getting, not the actual call to run test.bat.

Comment: You need to get the command line from the parent process ID. So loop through Processes twice, once to get ParentProcessID, then a second time to get it's CommandLine.

Comment: I did, but I'm getting the process that started cmd.exe, not the script name. So for example, if I run the script using powershell, the Parent Process name is cmd, and the grandparent process name is powershell, but interestingly the "CommandLine" attribute for the grandparent is empty.

Comment: It seems maybe I can get the script name by searching through the Console history. I'm trying to translate [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684965(v=vs.85).aspx) to C#, if I could get any help that would be great.

Comment: Start your script. Type in another command prompt, `wmic process get ProcessID, ParentProcessID, Name, commandline`. Although it won't show things typed. Start your script `cmd /c batfile.bat` and it will show. Try using a doskey macro to automate it `doskey batfile=cmd /c batfile.bat`